# How do I tree shake Three.js using WebPack or Rollup?

Tags: three.js, webpack, rollupjs

I've got a Three.js scene that only uses a portion of the library.

```
import {
    Scene,
    PerspectiveCamera,
    WebGLRenderer,
    BoxGeometry,
    MeshBasicMaterial,
    Mesh} from 'three';
```

But I still end up getting most, if not all, of the entire library (~500Kb minified). Has anyone had any luck with this? I have an [example GitHub](https://github.com/amboy00/threejs-webpack-attempt) that shows the code I'm using.

Comment: in general, I think JS devs have to start walking through how tree shaking are implemented in Rollup and Webpack, at the moment there is too much magic in how they work. I've also had the same issue a few times and it's hard to tell if libs are really as small as they can be.

Comment: I have been experimenting with this on and off a little lately, maybe you are interested to see? [repo](https://github.com/2pha/three-rollup-treeshake-test)

Answer (score 4):

I'm currently using WebPack2 in a project and switched to using the built-in tree-shaking. Let's walk through the steps:

- obviously, install current three.js via npm: `npm install three`
- in the webpack-config, we need to override what happens when you `import {Something} from 'three';` in your code. To do this, I use the [alias-setting](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-alias) of the resolver-config to use the alternate module-build that is included with newer three.js versions:

  ```
   {
     resolve: {
       extensions: ['.js'],
       modules: [SRC_PATH, 'node_modules'],
       alias: {
         'three': path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/three/build/three.module.js')
       }
     }
   }
  ```
- now, if you're using babel to transpile your javascript, you need to make sure that the plugin that compiles es6-modules to commonjs is not included. Otherwise the babel-tree-shaking simply won't find any es6-modules to shake (in case you are already using the es2015-preset, you can use `babel-preset-es2015-native-modules` instead). There's some more information about that in [this blog-post](http://www.2ality.com/2015/12/webpack-tree-shaking.html).

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, I still end up with a large file of the same size. With or without the alias, Webpack is already using the module file in `three`. Is this just something in the way three is written?

Comment: Will have another look at this soon and update here accordingly.

Comment: @Chris: I re-checked and unfortunately that is probably as good as it gets for now. If you look at the unminified output, you will see a lot of "unused harmony export" comments, so webpack did realize that they are not needed. However, webpack is currently unable to remove unused exports if they are used somewhere else in the code, even if used by an also unused other class. Neither did rollup provide any better results here.

Comment: That's what I suspected, but I'd hope it was an issue I overlooked. I appreciate you taking the time to look at this. Perhaps it's something I can bring up to the three.js folks.

Comment: After lots of trial & error I finally got bundling to work, but it was disappointing because the load performance wasn't any better than a pure [CDN](https://www.jsdelivr.com/) approach (likely because my host server cannot compete with a CDN server). [Skypack](https://docs.skypack.dev/) looks promising, but I haven't been able to get this to work using their pin URLs.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is that you need to run your import from the THREE src/ tree which is not in the build/ dir, you'd need to clone THREE to have a local src/ tree against which your application runs.

In particular, you could use src/Three.js which is a giant exporter of all the THREE modules. Or simply change your imports to refer to the src//module.js.

Then rollup would have the individual modules against which to run and thus omit unused code.

Edit: see https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/10328#issuecomment-290233801 for more